# In mongoDB why only the first replica set has all red lines ? whereas it does not used in the operations

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have a microservice architecture, where I have a chat service receiving a lot of traffic at burst , mostly when some of our user goes LIVE and start receiving 1000s of messsages and comments, we receive these webhooks and process them to store on our database.

In this last 7 day metrics I noticed in the metrics on mongoDB, that second and third replica shows orange line, which means they swithced the primary adn secondary, whereas the first replica only shows red lines.

1. Does this mean the first replica restarted multiple times this week ? but why as per the metrics its not clear, I can only see that its not being used as all
2. The other 2 replicas also shows the red lines, which I am aware of, I got alerts of high CPU usage and also needed to manually scale it vertically from M40 to M50 to handle.

Help in understanding this would be really aprreciated.

[image]

- I tried reading a lot about such issues online, understood the orange and red line behaviour, orange line is not primarily a big concern as multiple factors can play to make that happen
- I am confused on the red line for first replica.
- Also reading to improve the strategies to make sure that such bursts of traffic does not cause havoc in our system.

Comment: Did you try looking at the logs?